# Detecting inset images/videos from a video

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, face-detection, video-compression

I want to detect multiple rectangles in a video, each of which features a different content, but running simultaneously. This is typically seen during debates on news channels. For example, in the image below, there are 5 rectangles (each containing a person) that are of interest to me and I want to keep a track of them. I am planning to use C++ and OpenCV. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image: Frame]

Comment: Very interesting assignment.